Find the inverse of $1+x$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$.
I'm having trouble understanding the process behind the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. I know that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ is a field with the greatest common divisor of $1+x$ and $x^3-2$ being 1 since $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so there exists polynomials $r(x)$ and $s(x)$ such that $$1 = r(x)(x+1)+s(x)(x^3-2).$$Since $x^3 \equiv 2 \,(\text{mod } x^3-2)$, if we substitute $x^3$ for 2 we have $$1 = r(x)(x+1) + 0$$ so if we find $r(x)$, we find the inverse of $(x+1)$. I understand that we can use the extended euclidean algorithm to find a linear combination of our two polynomials $x+1$ and $x^3-2$, but I don't understand the process. Here's what I have
\begin{align}
x^3-2 &= (x+1)(x^2-x+1)+(-3) \\
x+1 &= (-3)\left(\frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\right)+0
\end{align}
How do I use this information to find $r(x)$?

The answer is in second last equation of your question, just put $x^3=2$ there.

You basically have it in your first line. (You have a typo, though: it should be $x^2 - x \color{red}{+} 1$.) Since $-3$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, you can divide through and get $(-1/3)(x^3 - 2) + (1/3)(x^2-x+1)(x+1) = 1$.

Don't mix cases, $x$ and $X.$
